# Module not found: Can't resolve 'pg-native'

Tags: database, postgresql, node-modules

I am trying to make a simple user login, and I want to store the hash and salt in a PostgreSQL database.

```
const {Client} = require("pg");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


const client = new Client({
   user:"xxxxxxx",
   host:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   database:"xxxxxxxxx",
   password:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   port: 1234
});
   
client.connect()

const saltRounds: number = 10;

const newUserHash = (username: String, password: String) => {
    bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err: Error, salt: String) {
        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err: Error, hash: String) {
            //send it to database
        });
    });
}
```

But I keep getting this error; `Module not found: Can't resolve 'pg-native'`. Using `import pg from 'pg'` has not worked for me and I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: If you are really using `pg-native` the see here [pg-native](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-native)  in particular `var Client = require('pg-native')`

Comment: Actually I think the better solution is found here [Native bindings](https://node-postgres.com/features/native): `const { Client, Pool } = require('pg').native`.